# Thread 1 signal:SIGABRT Error IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I recently upgraded an app I created from iOS 6 to iOS 7 (and Xcode 4 to Xcode 5). I then tried to run the app, and the build said it succeeded, however the app crashed and directed me to this code and the error message:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Thread 1 signal:SIGABRT

The console log is below in case that helps:

```
2014-01-14 14:30:39.791 Recipes[1808:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UIImageView: 0x8ba3e80; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ba3f10>> is associated with <UIViewController: 0x8b93c60>. Clear this association before associating this view with <UIViewController: 0x8b95690>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ab45e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018378b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ab43bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x00a31c99 -[UIView(Internal) _setViewDelegate:] + 242
    4   UIKit                               0x00ae3ecc +[UIViewController setViewController:forView:] + 40
    5   UIKit                               0x00ade921 -[UIViewController setView:] + 511
    6   Foundation                          0x005e6d28 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 133
    7   Foundation                          0x005e6253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    8   Foundation                          0x0064870a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    9   UIKit                               0x00c6ca15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018497d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x01aafb6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    12  UIKit                               0x00c6b56e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    13  UIKit                               0x00c6d2fb -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 165
    14  UIKit                               0x009ca3bb -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
    15  UIKit                               0x009ca6e9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    16  UIKit                               0x009c928f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
    17  UIKit                               0x009dd87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    18  UIKit                               0x009ddde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    19  UIKit                               0x009cb025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x02ea62f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x02ea5e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01a2fd65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01a2fa9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01a5a77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x01a59ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x01a598db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  UIKit                               0x009c8add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    28  UIKit                               0x009cad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    29  Recipes                             0x000022cf main + 93
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x02b4670d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The first line is telling you exactly what the issue is.  And without any code, it's not possible to provide you with more assistance than that.

Comment: You're adding a UIImageView to two different viewControllers at the same time. It mentions which one and which viewControllers on the first line.